# Numbers of the solution in a Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, cauchy-integral-formula

I am looking for an example for a real first order ODE which has  $0$, $\infty$ or exactly $1$ solution depending on the initial $x(t_{0})$ value.

The solution doesn't necessary has to have the domain of the full real line.
I was thinking about something which has  similar solutions like the functions on the following picture on $[0,\infty)$.
[image]

Is there any good method to figure out differential equations knowing their solutions?
If my task is to write a differential equation which has a solution $x(t)$, when does this task has a unique differential equation?

So far I used Itô formula for deterministic processes in these kind of problems. Perhaps it is a kind of "beyond the goal" solution. Is there any better idea?

Comment: I've just realized it is obviously a bad example. It clearly doesn't have the same derivate in a given t. In spite of this inconvenience I think the question is clear.

Comment: You get singular equations like $xy'+y=1$ that do not really have ordinary initial conditions at the singular points. The you get equations with non-unique solutions like $y=0$ in $y'=2\sqrt{|y|}$.

Comment: I think x'=2/t*x+1 t=/=0 is a good example for this.